# Serverless API offline testing recieving validation error when sending post req data to MongoDB via postman

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, postman, aws-serverless

I’m doing some backend testing of my serverless api via postman and the data I’m sending is resulting in `Users validation failed: email: Path email is required., name: Path name is required., password: Path password is required.`

**User Model**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
      validate(value){
        if(!validator.isEmail(value)){
          throw new Error ("Please enter correct email");
        }
      }
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
      type: String,
      default: "Normal",
    },
    created: {
      type: "Date",
      default: Date.now,
    },
    subscription: {
      type: String,
      default: "dev",
    },
    token: {
      type: String,
      default: "free",
    },
  { collection: "Users" }
);

userSchema.post("save", function (_doc, next) {
  _doc.password = undefined;
  return next();
});
```

**User Handler**

```
/* Create User*/
module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  Database.connectToDatabase()
    .then(() => {
      let body = querystring.decode(event.body);
      console.log(event.body)
      const randomKey = uuidv4();
      let newUser = new User({
        name: body.name,
        email: body.email,
        password: body.password,
        apiKey: randomKey.replace(/-/g, ""),
      });
    //console.log("TESTING")  
      newUser.save(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          callback(null, {
            statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
            body: err.message,
          });
        } else {
          callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(user),
          });
        }
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
        body: err.message,
      });
    });
};
```

**Data I'm sending via Postman**

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/prod/users' \
--header 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"name": "hello", "password": "pass", "email": "asdf@asf.com"}'
```

**Expected Results**

Sending the data should result in creation of new user and api key and store them in the MongoDB. I'm doing this without the express server, so I'm assuming router.post info, the data isn't being routed properly. If that is the case, what do i need to change or implement to be able to create a user via postman?

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass the data as key value pairs in `x-www-form-urlencoded`